# htaccess redirect phpbb to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need help with a redirect using htaccess since I moved my phpbb forum to a subfolder called "forum". So I want viewtopic.php?... to redirect to /forum/viewtopic.php?...
and viewforum.php?... to /forum/viewforum.php?...

I google all day and couldn't find an exact code to use so I tried to fiddle with the code to no avail.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !forum/
RewriteRule ^([view(.+)\.php(.+)])$ forum/$1 [QSA,NC,L,R=301]
```

I tried to catch both "viewtopic" and "viewforum" and then redirect it to /forum/ but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteRule ^view(.+)\.php$ /forum/$0 [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

- Because of the nature of the redirect (with the need to capture the entire request URI), there is no need to wrap it - you can just us `$0`.
- You were using square brackets in your capture, which which would not have helped in any way. Square brackets indicate a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

If the new rule works for you, change the `R` flag to `R=301` (as you had it previously), which will make the redirect permanent.

**Update:** Your entire `.htaccess` file should look like this now:

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ - [E=noabort:1]

# Redirect Forum
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteRule ^view(.+)\.php$ /forum/$0 [QSA,NC,L,R]

# WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The redirect rule must come *before* the WordPress rules.

Comment: Tried this, but it's not catching it at all.

Comment: Anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Have you got `RewriteEngine On` at the beginning?